# Nested for loops don't work correctly

Tags: java, for-loop

I am currently writing a game engine for a game I'm making. 
I'm writing a Map Object which uses Cell objects. A Cell is supposed to be a 128x128 area, which is represented by an array. Each int represents a object. However, when I run the following code for Cell generation:

```
private int[][] cellGen() {
    int[][] tempMap = new int[128][128];

    for (int x = 0; x < 128; x++) {
        int y = 0;
        for (y = 0; y < 128; y++) {
            tempMap[y][x] = itemGen();

        }
    }
    return tempMap;
}
```

However, it only generates one line of 128 ints, and doesn't fill the entire array. What am I missing that does this?

Here's `itemGen()`:

```
private int itemGen(){
    switch(biome){
        case 0: return (int)(5*Math.random());
        case 1: return (int)(5*Math.random())+5;
        case 2: return (int)(5*Math.random())+10;
        case 3: return (int)(5*Math.random())+15;
        case 4: return (int)(5*Math.random())+20;
        default: return 100;
    }
}
```

Here's the code I'm checking the entries with:

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cell c = new Cell();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c.rawCell()));
    }
}
```

Here's the complete code of my `Cell` class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Cell {
    private int[][] cell;
    private int biome; 

    public Cell(){
        this.cell = cellGen();
        this.biome = biomeGen();
    }

    private int itemGen() {
        switch(biome) {
            case 0: 
                return (int)(5*Math.random());
            case 1: 
                return (int)(5*Math.random())+5;
            case 2:
                return (int)(5*Math.random())+10;
            case 3:
                return (int)(5*Math.random())+15;
            case 4:
                return (int)(5*Math.random())+20;
            default: 
                return 100;
        }
    }

    private int biomeGen() {
        return (int)(5*Math.random());
    }

    private int[][] cellGen() {
        int[][] tempMap = new int[128][128];

        for(int x = 0;x<128;x++) {
            for(int y = 0;y<128;y++) {
                tempMap[y][x] = itemGen();
            }
        }

        return tempMap;
    }

    public int[][] rawCell() {
        return cell;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return Arrays.toString(cell);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems fine. Is that the entire and authentic code? What's up with that `int y = 0` line?

Comment: Looks like there's an off-by-one bug. Should be `x < 128` or `x <= 127` -- same with `y`.

Comment: Your loops have an off-by-one error: `0<=x<127` is only 127 items; you need `x<128` to get 128.

Comment: Any chance `itemGen` is faulty and only able to generate 127 or 128 elements?

Comment: Item gen just uses a random biome number that is generated when the cell is made. Here's my github; the code is in the cell class.  [link](https://github.com/brucelong/project-JPAG) Cant imagine why that would break.

Comment: there is an unknown variable "biome" in the itemGen method which is never declared or shown where it comes from.

Comment: Biome is in the cell class, it is randomly created when the cell is initialized. That method is also in Cell. It is named biomeGen

Comment: Please show the code where you check the entries (you can edit it into your question). This looks perfectly alright to me.

Comment: Here's one thing that might give you the impression that no ints are generated: Math.random() gives a uniform distribution over [0;1], so there's a 20% chance that 5*Math.random() cast to int will be 0, which means you'll end up with a 20% chance that you get a uniform distribution over {1;2;3;4;5}. Granted, the chance that this fills your matrix with 0 is vanishingly small, but that's all I can think of.

Comment: I am using Arrays.toString to print the array, but even if it was 0 wouldn't it still show?

Comment: Please post your test code. As it stands, there is nothing definite left to be said about your code.

Comment: public class main {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Cell c = new Cell();
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c.rawCell()));

 }

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working exactly the way you want it to - apart from your `Cell.toString()` method. If you have a look at that, you call `Arrays.toString(int[][] cell)`, which will of course give you a string representation of the two(!)-dimensional array `Cell.cell`. Now, what's in a two dimensional array? A bunch of one dimensional arrays! So what your `Cell.toString()` method (as well as your test code) does is print the addresses of the arrays in `Cell.cell`, which are of course not at all what you want. You want a matrix representation of `Cell.cell`, and since Java 1.5, we have `Arrays.deepToString(Object[] a)` to do that for us. But that'll put all of the string in one line, and you probably want the output string for your square matrix to be square, so you'll have to iterate yourself. Here's code to compare outputs.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cell c = new Cell();
        int[][] cell = c.rawCell();
        System.out.println("Arrays.toString:");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cell)); // ugly, ugly object addresses

        System.out.println("\n\n");

        System.out.println("Arrays.deepToString:");
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(cell)); // well this is basically alright, but it's all in one line

        System.out.println("\n\n");

        //now there's a pretty matrix! look at you, all filled with numbers
        System.out.println("Going down the levels by hand:");
        for(int i = 0; i < cell.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("[");
            for(int j = 0; j < cell[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(cell[i][j]);
                if(j != cell[i].length - 1) {
                    System.out.print(", ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("]");
        }

        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");

        // if you're dead set on using Arrays.toString(),
        // you'll have to go down to the very lowest level by hand
        System.out.println("Arrays.toString for each one-dimensional array:");
        for(int i = 0; i < cell.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cell[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

Now this wasn't really a difficult problem to figure out, except that it was way tougher than it should've been. There's a bunch of things you should take away from this:

- Post ALL relevant code. That means all code that actually plays
  any part in what comes out at your end that doesn't look the way it
  should (and certainly the output statements if you see numbers with @
  symbols in them, which should make you curious).
- Please try not to make people ask multiple times. The very first comment was asking "is that the entire [..] code?" - that should not have to be repeated.
- Look at the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5b%5d%29) of stuff you're using where you're not entirely, positively sure how they play along with your code if something doesn't work the way it should.
- Actually check your output, don't just gloss over it - you will immediately see that there are @ symbols in the output, and that never happens with `int`s.

I hope I'm not sounding too condescending, that is not the intention - to make this site work smoothly, communication is key. To become a better programmer, no one can do without attentiveness regarding their own code.

Comment: Thank you. I'm learning through this, so thanks again for your input.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int x = 0; x < 128; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 128; y++) {
        tempMap[x][y] = itemGen();
    }
}
```

try this

I am not sure that `< 127` was right i think you wanted `< 128`

Also `tempMap[y][x] = itemGen();` seems counter intuitive, unless otherwise needed perhaps you should do `tempMap[x][y] = itemGen();`

Right now you are filling a whole column before moving to the next column, where as it seems more intuitive to fill a whole row, before moving on to the next row.

Finally it makes sense to move the `int y = 0` to inside the for loop like so `for (int y = 0; y < 128; y++)` as you are recreating y every time x iterates anyways.

otherwise you may do it like so

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
for (x = 0; x < 128; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < 128; y++) {
        tempMap[x][y] = itemGen();
    }
}
```

you can say it does not work, but having run this code

```
int[][] table = new int[128][128];
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        for (x = 0; x < 128; x++) {
            for (y = 0; y < 128; y++) {
                table[x][y] = 1;
            }
        }
        for (x = 0; x < 128; x++) {
            String line = "";
            for (y = 0; y < 128; y++) {
                line += ", " + table[x][y];
            }
            out.println(line);
        }
```

I know that it does work.

Comment: Apparently eclipse used a old copy of my code; because it was at 128. The int y = 0 was just a test to see if that fixed it. Also, that code has the same bug; no more ints after 128

Comment: Your code does work, but whenever I change it to include even just my own array, it still generates as one row of 128, and stops. Test code:        private int[][] cellGen(){
   int[][] tempMap = new int[128][128];
         int x = 0;
         int y = 0;
         for (x = 0; x < 128; x++) {
             for (y = 0; y < 128; y++) {
                 tempMap[x][y] = 1;
             }
         }
   return tempMap;

  }

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with this loop first you have the condition set incorrectly. x < 127 and y < 127. It should be x < 128 and y < 128 or more generally and correctly x < tempMap.length and y < tempMap[i].length:

```
private int[][] cellGen(){
    int[][] tempMap = new int[128][128];
    for(int x = 0;x<tempMap.length;x++){ //loop over rows x is the row number
        for(int y = 0;y<tempMap[i].length;y++){ //loop over columns y is the column number
            tempMap[x][y] = itemGen();

        }

    }
    return tempMap;

}
```

Comment: Neither of these will cause only the first row to be filled. Actually, it doesn't matter if you assign in row-first order, or column-first order.

Comment: It could matter, although I believe in this case you are correct that it doesn't. And since it doesn't then why not just make it intuitive? In math did you ever order a x,y pair as y,x?